# Bokeh Ray glyphs not displaying tooltips

Tags: python, plot, tooltip, bokeh

I cannot get Ray glyphs in Bokeh (v2.2.3 with Python 3.8.6) to work with the HoverTool. The tooltips just won't show.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()


N = 9
x0 = np.zeros(N)
y0 = np.ones(N)
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N)
y = x**2
z = x + 1j * y

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x0, y=y0, length=np.absolute(z), angle=np.angle(z)))

fig = figure(title='', plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
fig.ray(x='x', y='y', length='length', angle='angle', source=source, line_width=2)
tooltips = [('length', '@length'), ('angle', '@angle')]
fig.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))
fig.x_range = Range1d(-2, 2)
fig.y_range = Range1d(0, 4)

show(fig)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ray glyphs do not currently support any hit-testing (i.e. they cannot be used with hover tools).

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/wiki/Glyph-Hit-Testing-Census

Your best alternative is `segment` or `multi_line`.

Comment: is there a technical reason for this ? any chance this will evolve in the future ?

Comment: No reason, except the list of potential things to work on is *very* long, and there are only so many hours in a day. This is an extremely low priority compared to many, many of those other things (you are the first person to ever ask about it in nearly ten years). So realistically, the best chance for it to ever be implemented is for a new contributor who is specifically motivated by this to decide to take it on.